# Google Cloud DNS - add a CNAME to another domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, google-cloud-platform

I can't add a CNAME to another domain - why and how can I fix?

My zone name is myapp.com. To add automated email security re spam, SendGrid (provider) wants me to add 3 CNAME records of the format:

```
 - mail.myapp.com             a123.b456.sendgrid.net
 - s1._domainkey.myapp.com    s1.domainkey.a123.b456.sendgrid.net
 - s2._domainkey.myapp.com    s2.domainkey.a123.b456.sendgrid.net
```

I can't do this. There is no error, the create button just does not work. I can however create CNAME records to my own domain.

Am I breaking the DNS rules or is this a Google Cloud limitation??

**EDIT:** Screen shot added.

Redacted parts are all myapp.com except the last two which is the SendGrid code. "Respond" is my subdomain. The existing CNAME is just a test to show I can add CNAMEs.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please add non-obscured screenshots of **exactly** how you're trying to add the records.

Comment: When adding the record, try omitting your domain. For instance, for the mail.myapp.com record, just specify "mail".

Comment: @EEAA - screenshot added. Re your second comment, I can't do that as myapp.com is hardcoded into the input field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ahh, I see the problem.

MX and CNAME records of the same name cannot exist within the same zone. You'll need to rename one of them.

Comment: Whaaaaaaat??? In all my reading, that was not mentioned! Simple things, hey?

Comment: Yep! `CNAME` records are mutually exclusive with the majority of record types. ([RFC 2181](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2181#section-10.1))

Comment: @AndrewB For once I beat you to answering a DNS question *and* wasn't stupidly wrong in my answer. :)

Comment: You *monster*. :(